# Cannot light a fire using a lens?

Tags: lens

A few days ago, on a sunny day, I found myself hiking in the woods and wanting to help fellow picknickers to light a fire with no matches or lighter.

However, I had my 17-55 f2.8 Nikon on my camera, so I thought: it's basically a telescope, why don't I concentrate the rays onto some dry paper to start a fire? I put the lens into manual, focused on the infinity, manually opened the iris (there is a handle to do that), and... nothing happened. The paper did not light up, the focused beam (a disk few milimeters across) did not even hurt when pointed on my hand.

What was wrong? A semi-decent magnifying glass starts a fire in no time. Is the lens not focusing the rays enough?...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about starting a fire.

Comment: Well yes, but it's using one of the key elements of a photographic camera, thereby learning more about its inner workings. Considering it unlikely that there could be a SE site on the topic of _fire_, what better place to ask this?

Comment: Not having another SE site where this would be on topic does not make it on topic here, sorry. What about Physics?

Comment: http://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: How about on http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @dpollitt Yes but there's no fire.stackexchange.com :-)

Answer (score 4):

You need a much longer focal length than 55mm to do this with a camera lens. The sun only occupies about a 1/2° arc of sky, yet at 55mm your lens is collecting light from about a 70° arc - the sun is occupying well less than 1% of your lens' field of view! And the entrance pupil (effective aperture) at 55mm and f/2.8 is only about 20mm. A cheap magnifying glass, on the other hand, is typically around 100mm wide and focuses the light from a much smaller angle of view.

Be aware that trying this with very long focal length lenses *can* damage the internal coatings of the lens if you allow the internal temperature of the lens to get too high. With lenses that use fluorite elements (currently Canon is the only major mass marketer of camera lenses that uses fluorite in their high end telephoto lenses) the heat can actually cause the elements to crack.

Comment: Doesn't it also have to do with the size of the front element? If you have two lenses with the same focal length but one has a larger front element, that one collects more energy from the sun than the smaller one and has more paper-burning potential.

Comment: @Justin Yes you are correct.  Both the collection aperture and the focal length matter, the first because of the total captured energy and the latter because of the focussed spot size.

Comment: I'd assume the aperture matters *much* more than the focal length. The aperture determines how much power is collected (I guess I recall that the power of the sun is something like 1 kW/m²) and the focal length determines how big the image of the sun disk is - longer focal length = bigger image = less energy density; a shorter focal length produces a smaller image = higher energy density = more heat, but is harder to focus (you are not looking through the SLR but rather play around with a gleamy spot on some wood), so one may guess that the hot spots are *about* the same size.

Comment: Well, the only light that matters is the light coming directly from the sun, so the most important factor is going to be *the surface area of the collection element;* i.e. the bigger the lens cap is, the more likely you're going to be able to start a fire with the lens that it caps.

Comment: @Justin It has to do with the size of the *entrance pupil*, which is the portion of the front element for which the light falling on it is allowed to pass through the aperture. The entrance pupil is easiest to conceptualize as the size the aperture appears to be when viewed through the front element.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft When starting a fire the ideal is not to focus an image of the sun as a disc on the material one is attempting to ignite (which would mean the longer focal length would have a larger disc than the shorter focal length). Rather it is to focus as much of the light collected by the lens on a single point. Such a focus does not result in an image because all of the light allowed to pass through the lens is concentrated on the same point and requires the lens to, in effect, focus *past* infinity.

Comment: If you don't believe narrow angle of view lenses concentrate more of the sun's energy than narrow angle lenses, then check out this link:

http://www.the-digital-picture.com/Help/Flare.aspx

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen You are correct that it is the aperture, or more accurately the *entrance pupil (effective aperture)*, size that matters. But it just so happens that most telephoto lenses have larger entrance pupils than most wider angle lenses because the entrance pupil of a longer focal length lens must be proportionally larger to achieve the same f-number as a shorter focal length lens. To get f/4 at 400mm requires an entrance pupil 100mm (a little over 4 inches) in diameter. To get f/4 at 40mm requires an entrance pupil 10mm (about 0.4 inches) in diameter.

Comment: I vote for focal length vs aperture because a wide angle lens no not focusing the parallel light at the width of the front element but the radial light. Otherwise your wide angle lens would be blurry at the edge. Seems the fire starting light is coming from the sun single point it's the focusing the most of that light in the same spot.