# Is a 3rd party (Tamron) lens safe to use on a Canon EOS 600D?

Tags: lens, dslr, third-party

Is it safe to use a Tamron lens with my Canon EOS 600D DSLR? Will it affect the sensor in any way?

Comment: It's no different from using any other lens.

Comment: What about the sensor health?

Comment: It's still no different from using any other lens. Why do you think a lens could possibly affect the sensor?

Comment: yes. I think so. cause original is original. Am i wrong?

Comment: Yes, you're wrong. There's a great big air gap between the lens and the sensor.

Comment: I meant not that the lens will touch to the sensor. I meant the impressions or light that will come from lens to the sensor. will it in any manner affect the sensor?

Comment: It's unclear from the original -- do you mean "affect" in the sense of _harm_, or do you mean will there be some effect on the quality of the image simply due to not being the same brand?

Comment: @mattdm you are correct. Also on the camera censor and battery due to different brand's circuitry in the lens

Comment: Which of the possibilities am I correct about?

Answer (score 9):

Third party lenses are generally safe to use. The only situation that is likely to damage the camera is if the lens focuses light weirdly and so creates a part of the camera a lot hotter than usually or overloads the sensor. This is very unlikely. Third party lenses (especially from manufacturers such as Tamron, Tonkina and Sigma) are usually of equal (and in some cases better) quality to their counterparts in the camera manufacturers line up.

As long as the lens has the appropriate mount for your camera then it will not damage your camera, and if it does it is a ***major*** defect. These defects occur at a rate that is many, many, many times lower than the rate of damage from other sources. Probably a similar rate to that of the original manufacturers lenses.

Comment: I think that "focus light weirdly" situation would be so rare that I'm willing to bet dollars to donuts that it _has never happened_. I'll even bet, for future donuts, that it _will never happen_. (That is, specifically because of being a third-party lens. Pointing a long telephoto of any brand directly at the sun is a different issue, but as we see from [this (closed) question](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/52375/cannot-light-a-fire-using-a-lens), you can't even do it on purpose with a wide-angle lens.)

Comment: @mattdm Indeed, but it may still be **possible**, if beyond the realms of **reasonable** possibility.

Answer (score 2):

No, using a third party lens will not damage your sensor in any way. There is a large air gap between the lens and the sensor, so there's no way that using any lens can damage the sensor.

(This assumes that you're using a lens for the correct lens mount. If you're using something for a *wildly* inappropriate lens mount *and* forcing the lens onto the camera somehow you could conceivably do some damage, but if you're forcing things onto the camera, you deserve everything you get).

Comment: I meant not that the lens will touch to the sensor. I meant the impressions or light that will come from lens to the sensor. will it in any manner affect the sensor?

Comment: Yes, of course it will affect the sensor, that's what you want it to do or you're not going to get an image. Will it damage the sensor? No - do you seriously think a company would sell something that blows up your camera? What would be the point of that?

Comment: What about the circuitry in autofocus mode or the battery usage?

Comment: Please ask new questions as a separate question, not as a comment on an answer. But the answer is still "no" - at this point, you seem to be trying to invent potential problems; there is no problem using third-party lenses.